# Node.js Express regex in app.get()

Tags: regex, node.js, express

There is some code:

```
app.get(/^\/test\?sid$/, function (req, res) {
    console.log('sid: ', req.params[0]);
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/login/index.html');
});
```

output:

```
Cannot GET /test?sid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express's router matches against the pathname only, not the whole URL including the query string.

Since there's no capturing group in your regex, `req.params` isn't going to be set.